# How to check day of month being 1,3,5,22,25,29

Tags: mysql

I have a field in my table that I keep the day of the month, example

But in this same field I am recording the information like this: 1,2,3,5,22

Today is 22 DAY (NOW ()) = 22

See that in my field the day is 1,3,5,22,25,27 as today is 22 should bring the record.

How can I check my field in mysql? Split? If so, how can I use it?
LIKE does not suit me!

Comment: Try using the function: [FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set).

Comment: PERFECT! ----- FIND_IN_SET( DAY( NOW( ) ) , dia )

Answer (score 0):

I used the `FIND_IN_SET (DAY (NOW ()) function, day)`

It worked perfectly.